# Why does the user receive a different link in their inbox than I provided to be sent?

Tags: php, email, sendgrid

I am very new to PHP and its my first time trying to send an email to users that created a new account to verify their email.

I used SendGrid and picked the CURL method.

The message I wrote to be received in the user's inbox is: `$message = "Hi $this->username! Account created here is the activation link http://localhost/php/eindwerk/verification.php?token=$token";`

But when I send the email I get this in the inbox:

> Hi John Doe! Account created here is the activation link https://u33180743.ct.sendgrid.net/ls/click?upn=pKXa2-2Bq6or-2BegBTFZie0czYlvp8kNju3WiWttHaOXGRJ84DhHUJPh2hLrgVpCqjj0OyCzCd6ZkOWUKyLtFbO97kFSnjSh4J2D6WH87jLzIWlGl-2FCnylhvyAGolZwp-2Fw8ejXISy7mWfp6-2F7BZhwxQJKt158LxE9OnzTIuMmWgmoQ-3DlfcX_16JrVhsLbFp7xu5pEDmC25xoN1wD30Ir4u-2BytKI2sf8N9whhmCQ6faIYQekmir-2F-2Figt2G5PtHeyg47CTwdekiz5pz-2FY72qGBGSB0fO-2B2eT60Me-2BdmXlURmb9dQqI4Q41swSO2wYzJPKboECbjxqoS1Gcl-2FqRJjX66xh9LxKk08IARECyZW6VYUc2dBLqSliBVT0Z4UHG6dhNZUjqv712bL4NHPenh6xy5SrsEAAenTs-3D

Code in SignUp.php:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
try {
    $user = new User();
    $user->setUsername($_POST['username']);
    $user->setEmail($_POST['email']);
    $user->setPassword($_POST['password']);
    $user->setToken(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32)));
    $user->save();
    $user->sendEmail("someone@example.com", "Hello World");
} catch (Throwable $e) {
    $error = $e->getMessage();  
}
```

}

Code in the function sendEmail:

```
function sendEmail($mail_to, $mail_subject){
    $token = $this->token;
    var_dump($token);

    $cURL_key = 'key';
    $mail_from = 'someone@example.com';
    $message = "Hi $this->username! Account created here is the activation link http://localhost/php/eindwerk/verification.php?token=$token";

    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\"personalizations\": [{\"to\": [{\"email\": \"$mail_to\"}]}],\"from\": {\"email\": \"$mail_from\"},\"subject\": \"$mail_subject\",\"content\": [{\"type\": \"text/plain\", \"value\": \"$message\"}]}",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "authorization: Bearer $cURL_key",
            "cache-control: no-cache",
            "content-type: application/json"
        ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    header("Location:index.php?success=" . urlencode("Activation Email Sent!"));
    exit();

    if ($err) {
        echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {
        echo $response;
    }}
```

Comment: You have click tracking turned on at Sendgrid, which transforms your URLs so that Sendgrid can track users' clicks for you. If you don't want that, then turn it off.

Comment: Also you need to invalidate/re-issue your API token, because you just posted it on a public website.

Comment: BTW: Editing it out of the question is inconsequential. It's in the edit history. Deleting the question is inconsequential, deleted questions are still visible and we already have the key copied down anyway.

Comment: I changed my API key. Thankyou for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Sammitch has answered your question in a comment, so I'll add it here for visibility.

There is nothing wrong with your code. Often times providers that deliver email mask links in order to track them. This excerpt is from SendGrid's documentation:

> Enabling Click Tracking causes all the links and URLs in your emails
> to be overwritten and pointed to either SendGrid’s servers or the
> domain you branded your link with so that any time a customer clicks a
> link, SendGrid can track those clicks. SendGrid can track up to 1000
> links per email.

If you don't need tracking/analytics from SendGrid, you can [turn off "Click tracking" in SendGrid](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/account-and-settings/tracking), which will keep your original URLs.